# Using Android NDK for an existing iOS app

Tags: android, ios, android-ndk

I'm bidding for a contract that insists on using the NDK for their iOS app.  Basically, they're arguing that they already have an iOS app and they want to use the Android NDK to have an Android app for it.

I'm sorry if this comes off ignorant.  I suggested that I could rewrite the entire app in Native Java/Kotlin but they don't see it any other way.  Is there a way to use Android NDK to create an android version of an existing iOS app?  I've never worked with the NDK.

Comment: That would depend entirely on the nature of the iOS app. If it's a game or something using OpenGL, written in C/C++, writing an NDK-centric Android app would be a reasonable solution. But if their iOS app is a typical Objective-C/Swift app, your approach of using Java/Kotlin is likely to make more sense.

Comment: Its a stock exchange app.  It's not even complicated to build.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android does not support either Objective-C or Swift, the two main development languages for iOS development. If the iOS app is written in either of those then there's nothing for it but to rewrite the app for Android.

As @CommonsWare says in their comment, if the app is written in C++ using OpenGL ES, which is cross-platform, then you might be able to share significant parts of the code between platforms.

You also say "I'm bidding for a contract that insists on using the NDK for their iOS app." That doesn't really make sense. The Android NDK does not support cross-development for iOS. You can't use it to develop iOS apps, full stop.